# How do I show/hide a row in Flex AdvancedDataGrid with hierarchical view, but flat ArrayCollection dataProvider

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I am working on a Flex AdvancedDataGrid with a flat ArrayCollection dataProvider. The requirement is that when the root nodes is closed, the root row should show a subtotal data and when the root nodes is opened, not show the subtotal data.

Anyone has a suggestion how to do it?

Thanks,

Patrick

Comment: do you want to display some additional data inside of root element inside of roots label?

Comment: Wait, I'm a little confused.  When you say that the root row should show subtotal data, where is it supposed to show it? Should it be in the first column?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the section in the Flex Help ["Creating Summary Rows?"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7bec.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7be5).  I did something similar where I embedded a chart in a grid using this feature.  I'll post the code if I can find it, but I know that I was able to complete the feature using only what you will find in this help section.